# Printing element in array python problems

Tags: python, arrays

I want to go through each element of an array I've created. However, I'm doing some debugging and it's not. Here's what I have so far and what it's printing out.

```
    def prob_thirteen(self):
       #create array of numbers 2-30
       xcoords = [range(2,31)]
       ycoords = []

       for i in range(len(xcoords)):
           print 'i:', xcoords[i]
```

output:

```
    i: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

Why does 'i' return my whole array and not just the first element: 2? I'm not sure why this is returning my whole array.

Answer (score 2):

```
xcoords = [range(2,31)]
```

This line will create an array of length 1. The only element in that array is an array of the numbers 2 -> 30. Your loop is printing the elements of the *outer* array. Change that line to:

```
xcoords = range(2,31)
```

This answer is correct for Python 2 because the [range function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) returns a list. [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) will return a `range` object (which can be iterated on producing the required values). The following line should work in Python 2 and 3:

```
xoords = list(range(2,31))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change `xcoords` so that it isn't a list inside a list:

```
xcoords = range(2, 31)
```

We don't need to iterate over a list using an index into the list using `len(xcoords)`.  In python we can simply iterate over a list like this:

```
for coord in xcoords:
    print "i: ", coord
```

If we did need to keep track of the index we could use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for i, coord in enumerate(xcoords):
    print str(i) + ":", coord
```